# "On time" vs. "in time"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, time, in-on

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“In time ” versus “on time”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17436/in-time-versus-on-time)

I don't know if there is any difference. Which of the following should I use?

> - I'll be on time to catch the train.
> - I'll be in time to catch the train.