# "In time" or "On time"?

Tags: prepositions, in-on

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“In time ” versus “on time”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17436/in-time-versus-on-time)
>   [“On time” vs. “in time”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66737/on-time-vs-in-time)

I am confused between usages of "On" and "In" in following sentence:

> Let the task be done _____ time.

Should I use "On" or "In" in this sentence?