# "in time" versus "on time" in this context

Tags: differences

Why does the answer key of my textbook suggest that only **on** can work in the following gap?

> I would strongly advise you to be _____ time to the lecture.

After checking [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17436/in-time-versus-on-time) topic, it is clear that **in** is the preferred preposition when it comes to events. Do you think it might be the author's mistake?

Answer (score 3):

"to be on time" means to be *punctual*.

> The movie started **on time**

The movie did not start earlier or later than stated in the showtimes.

"to be in time" means to arrive at a destination with some moments (or minutes) to spare.

> Dave's taxi got stuck in traffic but he was still **in time for** his flight.

Note the preposition "for". You can arrive in time *for* an event or an appointment.

Thus the textbook answer is the most appropriate

> I would strongly advise you to be **on time** to the lecture.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a mistake.

'On time' means 'not later the exact time'.

For example, students should be in the lecture room exactly at the appointed time.

'In time' means 'before the exact time'.

For example, students should be in the lecture room before the  appointed time.

The author of the textbook wants to underline the fact that it's not necessary to come before the lecture, and it's quite all right to enter the lecture room at the appointed time.

Comment: `The author ... wants to underline the fact that it's not necessary to come before the lecture.` where does it say that? If Ss arrive ten minutes before the lecture they're not going to find the doors locked.

Comment: Your reason (about the locked door) is quite possible.

Comment: But it's not mentioned in the question.